# Need advice? What to choose Servlets or Spring MVC?

Tags: servlets

I have an application in mind which I want to develop. I am targeting the application for a big user base, consider it as a social app. But I am not 
sure whether to write it with Servlets or Spring MVC. 
I have a good grip on Servlets, it would be easy for me to develop, but when it comes to Spring I am still novice. 
I am not clear what difference would it make if the app is developed on Servlets rather than Spring MVC. 
Scalability or some factors like that?

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might take you some time to learn Spring but..., once you do, it will provide powerful tools to code.

Answer (score 0):

Its always good to go for Spring framework as it provides:

- Dependency Injection support
- Spring MVC: easy to customize
- Data access support
- Spring Security
- AOP support etc..

Clearly, Spring provides more functionality than servlets. But if your app is very simple enough, you can go for Servlets.